# "Error while creating the database: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I keep getting "Error while creating the database: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" when trying to create a database. I am using NetBeans 21, JDK 21, and db-derby-10.17.1.0-bin.How do I fix this problem?

I tried different derby files

Comment: It's better if you could share your code or work so far

Comment: Could you follow these https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add more information?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.